# VSCode git commit not working but not generating errors

Tags: javascript, github, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a portfolio website and a few days ago created the github and began commiting changes. I made 2 commits that day, but none of my other commits the day after and today have synced to the repository. I am saving files, staging changes, and not getting errors. Really not sure how to fix this.

Comment: what happens when you `git push`?

Answer (score 1):

Did not realize I needed to run `git push` for the commits to show up in github, thank you!